# JMeter If Controller

Tags: jmeter

not too sure if this is a user error but I can't seem to get this working.  I have a test that returns 200 and this always hits the If controller, but the following fails.

I get a productID, if this is nested then i get the first one.
Regex is
prodID
"ProductId":(.*?),
$1$
0

Then as I want to use this in another thread group I cjhange to a property:
${__setProperty(prodID-${__threadNum},${prodID},)}

Then i use If Controller as
${__P(prodID-${__threadNum})} == "18"

Then it runs the same regex, but this time with $2$

Problem is that the If Controller isn't getting run on any, is there a way I can see this, or even is the above correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) run its children if the expression evaluates to `true`

You're giving `18 == "18"`, it is not equal to `true` therefore the children are not getting executed.

I would suggest using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) instead like:

```
${__groovy(props.get('prodID-' + ctx.getThreadNum()).equals('18'),)}
```

where

- `props` is a shorthand for [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class instance holding [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- `ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands